# VBA:Lock and change color of excel cells

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Following is my vba code,where i`m trying to get data and assign it to a cell.Now,all I need to do is to lock these cells after filling. And there are many cells where I have to do this, all I got is 'qa' part is same in all the cell names I have to fill.So I have to check if 'qa' is part of the cell name,if yes then lock that complete cell and change the color.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("Book.aa.a.qa.qq.le.").RefersToRange = Doc.getAttribute("le")
ActiveWorkbook.Names("Book.bb.a.qa.qq.lf.").RefersToRange = Doc.getAttribute("lf")
ActiveWorkbook.Names("Book.cc.a.qa.qq.lg.").RefersToRange = Doc.getAttribute("lg")
ActiveWorkbook.Names("Book.dd.a.qa.qq.ll.").RefersToRange = Doc.getAttribute("ll")
```

How to do this?
Please suggest a function for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Approximately how many cells are you looking at?

Comment: 30 cells...but i`ve other same excel sheets that differs these cells.

Comment: `Approx` means maximum cells that you would get in any sheet? I am referring to the upper limit :)

Comment: @bonCodigo:Then it`s 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you had asked almost similar question earlier. The only different here that you are specifically asking if the name contains `qa`, you would have been able to fix that by now with the given details in that answer. Anyway, here I use `Like` operator on `IF` to do the check on the same code,

```
Dim strName As String, objName As Name, strID As String

Sheet1.Unprotect
For Each objName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    strName = objName.Name
    If InStr(1, strName, "book", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        strID = Mid(strName, InStr(1, strName, ".", vbTextCompare) + 1, 1)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Names(strName).RefersToRange
            .Value = doc.getAttribute(strID)
            '--change here
            If strName Like "*qa*" Then
              .Interior.Color = vbRed
              .Locked = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next
Sheet1.Protect
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. It works. But nowhere you`ve mentioned the max cells(50). Why did you ask me for that?

Comment: And is there a way we can check if the selected cell is within the range mentioned???? like If InStr(1, strName, "book", vbTextCompare) > 0 and range() ???

Comment: For your first comment: I am not a big fan of iterating through cells unless it's really required. There is another way to do this, but I believe this is alright for 50 cells.. Given you only have named ranges till 50 rows.. or so. For the second comment: Withing which range? Within entire cell range? Can you clarify it a bit more please.

Comment: yeah...within range(B1:I35)...there are headers included in this range,that`s why I had to put colors to those particular cells.

Comment: You don't need that, I have included it since it was the main code you were working on... you can smiply remove that entire part `strID = Mid(strName, InStr(1, strName, ".", vbTextCompare) + 1, 1)` and `.Value = doc.getAttribute(strID)`.. but then I am not sure why you want to colour that cell when there's no data in it... just because the name matched?

Comment: bonCodigo:Thanks for replying.No actually i`ll fill data to those. But I wanted to lock those explicitly. And yeah i`ve removed the code part. Thanks a lot.